# Como tomar valores especificos de una base de datos y ponerlo en una lista en una plantilla flask?

Tags: html, python, flask

Hola recien estoy tratando de hacer una lista con valores de una tabla pero solo puede hacer esto con un solo valor, la cosa es que tengo una tabla relacionada con otras 3 tablas y en el modulo de insertar los datos queria que en una lista se llamen los datos de la otra tabla para solo selecionarlos, esto es lo que he logrado hasta ahora, agradeseria mucho una ayuda.

python

```
@app.route('/t',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Consulta():
    g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=AUS_COMPUTO02\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=WEBSERVICE; Trusted_Connection = yes;')

    cur= g.con.execute("SELECT *FROM PROVEEDOR WHERE DECRIPCION  = '{}' ".format('INDUVECA'))
    format='CHEF','INDUVECA'
    posts = [dict(ID_PROVEEDOR=row[0], DECRIPCION=row[1] ) for row in cur.fetchall()] 
    g.con.close()
    print(posts)
    return render_template('consulta.html', posts=posts)
```

html

```
{% block content %}

<from name="des" action="{url_for('ad')}" method='POST'>

    <input list="week" type="text" name="dia" />
     {% for p in posts %}
     <datalist id="week">
     <option value="{{ p.ID_PROVEEDOR }}" name="dia"> {{ p.DECRIPCION }}  </option>
     <option value="{{ p.ID_PROVEEDOR }}" name="dia"> {{ p.DECRIPCION }}  </option>


        </datalist> 
         {% endfor %} 
    </form>


{% endblock %}>
```

con eso me funciona pero solo me llama un dato

Comment: Solo un detalle, no debería ser DEsCRIPCIÓN con una s? Compruebas que la consulta te devuelve todos los resultados? Tienes que aislar si el problema está al consultar los datos o al intentar meterlos en el html.

Comment: es algo de pueba luego cuando balla a pasar al prollecto final lo arreglo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por la ayuda esta fue la solocion del codio por si a alguen le interesa luego:

Python

g.con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE=W; Trusted_Connection = yes;')

```
cur = g.con.execute("SELECT *FROM PROVEEDOR")

des = [dict(ID_PROVEEDOR=row[0],DECRIPCION=row[1] ) for row in cur.fetchall()]

g.con.close()
print(des)

return render_template('test.html', des=des )
```

y en html

```
Proveedor<br action="{url_for('t')}" method='POST'>
                <input list="des" type="number" name="idp" />


             <datalist id="des">
              {% for  d in des %}
               <option value="{{ d.ID_PROVEEDOR }}" > {{ d.DECRIPCION }} </option> 
                  {% endfor %}
                  </datalist> 

                </br>
```

El resultado

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que redefines tu `datalist` en cada iteración del `for`, debes hacer:

```
{% block content %}

<form name="des" action="{url_for('ad')}" method='POST'>
    <input list="week" type="text" name="dia"/>
    <datalist id="week">
    {% for p in posts %}
        <option value="{{ p.ID_PROVEEDOR }}" name="dia"> {{ p.DECRIPCION }}  </option>
    {% endfor %} 
    </datalist> 
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Tienes además un error tipográfico, no es `<from name="des" ...>`, debe ser `<form name="des" ...>`.

Comment: ¿Que pretendes con  `format='CHEF','INDUVECA'` ? esa linea no hace absolutamente nada (simplemente crea una tupla que no se usa nunca  llamada  `format` con las cadenas 'CHEF'  e 'INDUVECA'). Por cierto, usar formateo de cadenas para construir la query es una mala práctica, deberías parametrizar.  Tu consulta a la BD es actualmente `"SELECT *FROM PROVEEDOR WHERE DECRIPCION  = 'INDUVECA'"` y la lista se construye correctamente en base a esa consulta . ¿Acaso quieres que te retorne todas las filas en las que "DESCRIPCION" sea "INDUVECA" o "CHEF"?

Comment: Con la última edición pasas una lista de tuplas (una por cada fila) al template, tendrías que modificar la forma en la que iteras en el. No obstante sigo sin entender cual es el resultado que esperas obtener ni que quieres decir con "desordenado", el orden es el de las filas de tu tabla. Si pudieras agregaras a la pregunta un snippet html a modo de ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener y la estructura de tu base de datos posiblemente terminaríamos antes.

Comment: ¿En base a que columna de la tabla? Si quieres ordenar la lista lo más simple y eficiente es hacerlo mediante la query.